# How can I query a column which has apostrophes in it with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a php MySQLi class to be more secure that MySQL, but I have a problem.

I have a column of data which contains apostrophes in it. I am comparing the column against a variable that has NO apostrophes, it's a clean string, from my url. In my old code I could easily just do a Replace(category_name, '''', '') in the SQL statement, and apostrophes wouldn't become a factor.

If I throw this into phpmyadmin, it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT merchant_category
FROM products
WHERE Replace( category_name, '''', '' ) = 'childrens accessories'
ORDER BY merchant_category
```

But with MySQLi this is a real problem, as it won't parse them:

```
        $params = array();
    $params[0] = "Replace(category_name, '''', '')";
    $params[1] = $this->db->escape($this->cleanDBValue(requestQS("cat1")));

    //print_r($params);

    $rs = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT merchant_category FROM products WHERE ? = ? ORDER BY merchant_category ", $params);
```

The data I'm trying to match with the query is:

```
children's accessories
```

And I'm not getting any results. How can I get round this?

Comment: What do `cleanDBValue` do and `requestQS()` do? One of them is most likely the culprit, and chances are you need neither. You could switch to using prepared statements, then you wouldn't even need `escape()`

Comment: cleanDBValue just removes the hyphens from the string and replaces with spaces (as this is what the DB value will look like), requestQS is my custom way of pulling in $_GET without checking if it's set. So these function are fine. The problem is this surely: $params[0] = "Replace(category_name, '''', '')";

Comment: As soon as that gets put into the SQL statement the apostrophes must get stripped?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that you already use parametrized queries. No need for escape() then, you're likely double-escaping the data. I doubt however whether you can use a `?` for the column name, put the `replace()` directly into the query

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It generates this error: WHERE Replace(category_name, &#39;&#39;&#39;&#39;, &#39;&#39;) = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code.

1. **You can bind data literals only**. Not identifiers. Not Mysql functions. Not various SQL parts. But data literals only.
2. The way you did it with your old code is awful. Instead of properly escaping your input data, you "escaped" data that is already in the database.

So, you have to get rid of both these things and make your query as simple as

```
$param = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['cat1']); //yes, I don't trust your functions
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT merchant_category FROM products 
        WHERE category_name = ? ORDER BY merchant_category";
$rs = $this->db->rawQuery($sql, array($param));
```

if it won't work - debug it. But you have to make it work this way only. Without replaces and stuff.

**Update:**
I got it.
You're trying to match URL slugs against category names.
That's wrong way.
Add another field to your table, contains exact slug from the URL.
And then match this one.
Otherwise you'll be in constant trouble.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing! And that's a good idea and far more simple in the long run.